# CSS absolute property

Tags: css, css-float

[**Fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/amolhadkar/d7paL/) I want two div with 100% height. 
1 div with background image and one color. 
both should equally in height in any resolution.
please help me.

```
.loginImage { width: 100%; }

.loginBox {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
   <div class="wrapper-login">
   <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="images/loginImage.jpg" alt="Cargo CRM" class="loginImage"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 loginBox"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I can't really imagine what you're trying to have, could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle That would be helpful so we can see the issue :)

Comment: please check the link

Comment: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d7paL/7/)

```
.col-xs-6 {
    width: 47.66666667%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:left;
}
.col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:left;
}
.loginImage {
    width: 100%;
}
.loginBox {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
}
.wrapper-login {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
}
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: If i remove "position:absolute" then "content" div height not matching with "side" div. I want both should me equal height in all resolution.

Comment: i didnt mentioned postion in my css :(

Comment: can you please check fiddle link